# Sync a FileReader in a for loop: Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, upload, filereader

I am trying to implement a JavaScript program to read a bunch of CSV files from a particular directory containing sub-directories. To do so, I am thinking of using Javascript to read multiple files using `webkitdirectory` and reading the files and then using java to push them.

HTML Form

```
<input id="csv" type="file" multiple webkitdirectory directory>
<input type="button" onclick="readCSV()" value="Submit">
```

JavaScript to Read Files

```
function readCSV(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv");
    var fileCount = fileInput.files.length;
    if( fileCount != 0) {
        alert(fileCount);
        var reader;
        for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function ()  {
                document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
               // Once the file is read, Send it to JavaServlet to save on server.
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[i]);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Select a File");
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that the code runs successfully when only one file is selected but breaks when multiple files are selected. I think the problem is in sync read. But I couldn't find a way to either sync read or pause the loop while the reader object completely reads the file.

Comment: you need to collect the many and change the way you show them from something that's made to display one into something that shows many.

Comment: Sorry, Can you share some more information on your suggestion. The problem is that the above code is not reading files when the count is more than one.